# Wont update ppa repositories

Tags: updates, sudo

I have been having this problem recently. Everytime I add a ppa it says click enter, so it succeeds. Then I need to run sudo apt-get update in order to update the ppa. So when I run this this comes up.[image]

Comment: If you visit the launchpad website [https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and click on the dropdown box indicating **series**, you will find that this particular PPA was not been released for yakkety yet.

Comment: This ^^^ also apllies to the other PPAs giving error. That is to be expected until the devs updted them to support 16.10.

Comment: ok thanks a million :) you should post this as an answer , CharlesGreen or CelticWarrior